# SQL Server : executing query conditionally

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have `Employees` tables in the database with a column `EmpID` which was changed to `ID`. I want to use the same query in both the old and new table and get the same result depending on the condition.

I have tried the following:

```
IF (COL_LENGTH('Employees', 'EmpID') IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT EmpID, NAME, SEX, SALARY
    FROM Employees
    WHERE EmpID IS NOT NULL
ELSE
    SELECT ID, NAME, SEX, SALARY
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
```

But when I run the query in the new table, I get column name `EmpID` doesn't exist error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have table "Employees" and column "EmpID" in it?

Comment: Do you have multiple databases in that server? If so, just pus "use databasename" on top before IF statement.

Comment: Depending on other things you're doing, you may be able to create a [`view`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that makes it appear as if both columns are in the table. After all of the references to the old column name have been cleaned up you can delete the view and use the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the *compile* stage versus the *execution* stage.  The code is initially compiled, where the tables and columns are validated.

Your problem is that the column doesn't exist, so you are getting a compile failure.

You can fix this using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
IF (COL_LENGTH('Employees', 'EmpID') IS NOT NULL)
    SET @sql = N'
Select EmpID, NAME, SEX, SALARY
From Employees
Where EmpID IS NOT NULL'
ELSE
    SET @sql = N'
Select ID, NAME, SEX, SALARY
From Employees
Where ID IS NOT NULL'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without dynamic SQL using [this approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i/66755#66755).

```
SELECT ISNULL(CA.ID, CA.EmpID) AS ID,
       CA.NAME,
       CA.SEX,
       CA.SALARY
FROM   (VALUES(NULL, NULL)) V(ID, EmpID)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID, /*Resolved from Employees if present or "V" otherwise */
                           EmpID, /*Resolved from Employees if present or "V" otherwise */
                           NAME,
                           SEX,
                           SALARY
                    FROM   Employees) CA
WHERE ISNULL(CA.ID, CA.EmpID) IS NOT NULL;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/UKOAM64449)**

Comment: Thank you Martin. This is a perfectly working solution, but given the number of the tables I joined and the complexity of my query, I will go with the dynamic SQL. The code I provided above is just a sample describing my problem, otherwise  my code is more than 150 lines. Thank you again.